# My ubuntu vm has a weird ip address. Cant Portforward my apache server in my router settings with it

Tags: virtualbox, apache2

I created a simple apache2 server on my ubuntu virtual machine. Now I want to make it accessible to devices outside my network. I did the same thing with my windows computer. Did the port forwarding for the pc's ip and it worked. Tried the same thing with the ubuntu vm apache server but the ip address my ubuntu vm has is weird. Its 10.0.2.25. The ip of my windows pc where the port forwarding worked was 192.168.178.23.

I hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: If you change your Network card settings in the VM itself from NAT to Bridged, then your OS in the VM should get a 192.168.178.xxx IP address.

Comment: Please read up on "private IP ranges".

Answer (score 1):

this is cause your vm is in NAT mode, therefore you see this "weird" address. It's not weird, it's a other network with a different subnet. The VM can communicate through your PC (your network stack through natting).

To communicate directly with your VM from the outside, the simplest solution would be a Bridge Mode for your virtual Interface. That shall be configured in your hypervisor solution (virtual box).

[Image of the bridge mode nic settings in virtualbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3UBT.png)

Hope this helps!

Some further notes for your research:

> What are the different private IP address ranges? Private IP
> addressing uses both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.
>
> Private IPv4 addresses have the following class configurations:
>
> - Class A IP addresses. Configurations range from 10.0.0.0 to
>   10.255.255.255. This class is for large networks and has 8 bits for the network and 24 bits for hosts.
> - Class B IP addresses.
>   Configurations range from 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255. This class is
>   for medium networks and has 16 bits for the network and 16 bits for
>   hosts.
> - Class C IP addresses. Configurations range from 192.168.0.0 to
>   192.168.255.255. This class is for smaller networks and has 24 bits for the network and 8 bits for hosts.

For further infos look [here](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/private-IP-address).